# How to fix this error: type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, jsonobjectrequest

I want remove key and value for ProductCharacteristic ->name. How it can be done in Java and how to fix this error?
type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

This is my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "0028167072_CO_FIX_INTTV_1008_P3909_IDX0",
    "status": "Active",
    "startDate": "2023-02-12T22:00:00Z",
    "place": [
      {
        "id": "8",
        "apartment": "578",
        "role": "QA",
        "@referredType": "street"
      }
    ],
    "ProductCharacteristic": [
      {
        "id": "CH_100473",
        "valueId": "CH12_1000374_VALUE04141",
        "value": "LTS",
        "name": "Computer"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Replace with your actual JSON string of load JSON from file
  String jsonString = "json above";
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
  JSONArray productCharacteristics = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ProductCharacteristic");
  // Iterate through each "ProductCharacteristic" object and remove the "name"
  // key-value pair
  for (int i = 0; i < productCharacteristics.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject productCharacteristic = productCharacteristics.getJSONObject(i);
    productCharacteristic.remove("name");
  }
  String updatedJsonString = jsonObject.toString();
  System.out.println("Modified JSON:\n" + updatedJsonString);
}
```

But this code is not working,I have error message:org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is an array, not object - `[...]` denotes an array, `{...}` denotes an object. [Json specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [left bracket and ends with ]right bracket.

You need to parse to an array and work with it:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
//get first, since the array contains only 1 element
JSONArray productCharacteristics = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("ProductCharacteristic");
```