# Cannot deserialize instance of `pojo.SuperRoot` out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Restassured is unable to deserialise the JSON response into my POJO classes (this could be related to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510083/cannot-deserialize-instance-of-object-out-of-start-array-token-in-spring-webserv).

My Super root class

```
public class SuperRoot {
    private List<Root> root; //includes getters & setters
}
```

```
public class Root { //includes getters & setters
    public List<Object> breeds;
    public String id;
    public String url;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public List<Category> categories;
}
```

My JSON which is supposed to be deserialised looks like below:

```json
[
    {
        "breeds": [
            
        ],
        "id": "1jm",
        "url": "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/1jm.jpg",
        "width": 401,
        "height": 600
    },
    {
        "breeds": [
            
        ],
        "id": "75q",
        "url": "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/75q.jpg",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 333
    },
    {
        "breeds": [
            
        ],
        "id": "86o",
        "url": "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/86o.jpg",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 344
    }
]
```

deserialisation should be successful since Root class will have a list of smaller JSONs

Github project link https://github.com/apoorvSinha/catProject

Comment: [How to fix this error: type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78006229/how-to-fix-this-error-type-org-json-jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject). While not an exact duplicate (it's about different library), the underlying problem is the same - you are trying to deserialize json array into an object. You should deserialize into a collection of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved when I used TypeReference like below

```
List<Root> cat =new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.asString(), new TypeReference<List<Root>>(){});
        for(Root st: cat) {
            System.out.println(st.getHeight());
}
```